# TFS 2012: cant set 80 port to web access

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

When I add new binding to 80 port for TFS web access App on IIS:
[image]

my build service does not work but:

[image]

How can I fix my build service and save binding to 80 port? Or is there another way to get access to TFS WebAccess on 80 port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin Hinshelwood has a blog post on this titled: [TFS 2012 – Issue: Stuck builds in Team Foundation Build with no build number](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/tfs-2012-issue-stuck-builds-in-team-foundation-build-with-no-build-number/)

Long story short, your build config needs to allow multiple host headers